# How to make a horizontal slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have to make a horizontal month slider which will have two pointers which will be used to select month intervals.Can this be done in sencha or i will have to use jquery.However if any one knows how to do that or have any links please answer........

Comment: Get some ideas from [here](http://wordpress.org/tags/jquery-slider)

Comment: hey thanks everyone for voting me down......i got the solution on      http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/

Comment: +1..Downvote is not necessary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5:

```html
Month: <input type="range" min="1" max="12">
```

or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

```js
$("#slider").slider();
```

```html
Month: <div id="slider"></div>
```

---

If you want the user to select a date, here's [a more convenience way](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to do it:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();

Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```